# WebService Problem Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I just created my first Web Service.

I use:

- IIS 7.5
- VS 2008
- .Net 3.5

After install my IIS and browse to my asmx file in IE I get the follow Error:

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
>   Handler "ScriptHandlerFactory" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

I googled it since 2 hours but don't find a solution.

My Config is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
               </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <!-- 
                Legen Sie beim Kompilieren debug="true" fest, um 
                Debugsymbole in die kompilierte Seite einzufügen. 
                Da dies die Leistung beeinträchtigt, sollte der 
                Wert nur beim Entwickeln auf "True" gesetzt werden.
            -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
                Der Abschnitt <authentication> ermöglicht die Konfiguration 
                des Sicherheitsauthentifizierungsmodus, mit dem 
                ASP.NET eingehende Benutzer identifiziert. 
            -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
                Der Abschnitt <customErrors> ermöglicht die Konfiguration 
                der Vorgehensweise bei unbehandelten Fehlern während 
                der Anforderungsausführung. Insbesondere können 
                Entwickler HTML-Fehlerseiten konfigurieren, die anstelle 
                einer Fehlerstapelüberwachung angezeigt werden.

            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
                <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
                <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
            </customErrors>
            -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
            Der system.webServer-Abschnitt ist zum Ausführen von ASP.NET-AJAX unter
            Internetinformationsdienste 7.0 erforderlich. Für frühere Versionen von
            IIS ist er nicht erforderlich.
        -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post your web.config so that we can help you.  This error is most likely due to a configuration error.

Comment: Try MSDN search for Microsoft-specific issues before google: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=ManagedPipelineHandler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay... found it.
1 of 1000 sites in Google says: Check if ASP.Net in IIS 7 is correctly installed -  and: Yes, it was not.
In Windows 7 installer for IIS it is not automatically selected.

Comment: Glad you found it. FYI, the first several results from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=ManagedPipelineHandler say the same thing.

Comment: Thank god for SO. I had the exact same issue and I had thought that ASP.NET was already installed as my MVC app worked fine! Thank you :)

Answer (score 25):

Another potential scenario for this error appears if you install the .NET 4 framework before IIS.  If ASP.NET is installed, but you still get this error, try the following command as an administrator:

```
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

That path might not be exactly the same as the one on your machine, but it should be close.

Comment: Note that this method is not supported in windows server 2012 (and later, presumably) it tells you to use the new server manager.

Answer (score 2):

Gobsmacked ... didn't expect this to work but it did for me.

Simply ran:

```
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: Three years later and this is still a valid solution :P

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue but it is resolved by doing the following:

1. Open cmd as administrator
2. Type: `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -I`
3. Press enter

This will register the `DotNetFramework`.